# Show only values greater than 100 mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
farmid chickens cows horses
10     104      50   2
12     62       110  7
17     74       12   154
```

I want to query the table and only display values that are greater than 100.  Output should look like this

```
farmid chickens cows horses
10     104      
12              110 
17                   154
```

Does anyone have suggestions for how I can make this work?

I have tried this:

```
SELECT farmid, chickens, cows, horses
FROM farms
WHERE chickens >=100 OR cows>=100 OR horses>=100;
```

however, it returns

```
farmid chickens cows horses
10     104      50   2
12     62       110  7
17     74       12   154
```

Comment: Please format the table better so it is easy to understand.

Comment: @StutiRastogi Thanks!

Comment: If you tried something, post it here so others can take a look

Comment: It is behaving correctly. Each row has one of those elements with a value >=100. You can use a `case` statement to format the results and blank out the values that don't apply, but formatting results is not exactly something you want to do here

Comment: how can i return only the values greater than 100?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Quantities of chickens, cows, and horses are all the same kind of thing, so no need for separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all table rows, if you only want the rows where at least one of the `chickens`, `cows` or `horses` are >= 100, include the last line as well.

```
SELECT 
    farmid,
    CASE
        WHEN chickens >= 100 THEN chickens
        ELSE NULL
    END AS chickens,
    CASE
        WHEN cows >= 100 THEN cows
        ELSE NULL
    END AS cows,
    CASE
        WHEN horses >= 100 THEN horses
        ELSE NULL
    END AS horses
FROM
    <enter table name here>
WHERE chickens >= 100 OR cows >= 100 OR horses >= 100
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the chickens, cows, horses cells with values lower then 100 to be null or empty, you should use case ... when.

For example...

```
select 
  (case when chickens > 100 then chickens else null end case) as chickens,
  (case when cows > 100 then cows else null end case) as cows,
  (case when horses > 100 then horses else null end case) as horses
from table_name
where
  chickens > 100 OR cows > 100 OR horses > 100
```

Comment: Would `''` be better than `null`? Not sure what is idiomatic in MySQL

Comment: I don't think you need `ELSE NULL`.  @AluanHaddad That would then technically require a cast somewhere, and that's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the WHERE clause for this.

Syntax:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

You can use OR and the > symbol in your WHERE clause to get the required result.

```
SELECT farmid,
    CASE WHEN chickens > 100 THEN chickens ELSE NULL
    END as chickens,
    CASE WHEN cows > 100 THEN cows ELSE NULL
    END as cows,
    CASE WHEN horses > 100 THEN horses ELSE NULL
    END as horses,
from tableName 
WHERE chickens > 100 OR cows > 100 OR horses > 100
```

This will select farmid, and depending on the case of which value is > 100, it will select that column value. It should work even if more than one column has  value > 100.

Comment: I have tried a where clause with chickens>=100 OR cows>=100 OR horses>=100 and I get all results.  What should I do differently?

Comment: Because we were using SELECT *, you can use SELECT farmid, if that's all you want.

Comment: I want to see farm Id and the value that is greater than 100

Comment: You would need a case statement in SELECT to blank out the values you do not want.

Comment: Check the edited answer and see if that works for you.